# Search all files in folder for numerous strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with password protected workbooks (same password) for all the branches in our company, Liverpool, Manchester etc.

In each workbook is a simple table that shows sales data, a sales number, name, email address, stock code etc, sometimes on 3 worksheets in each workbook

I then have a master workbook that has a list of stock codes in it.

I need to be able to create a macro that searches through all of the workbooks in row F and if it finds a matching value for any of the stockcodes, copy that row and paste it to a new worksheet in the master workbook with the title of the worksheet being the same name as the file name it found it in, with the rows of data throughout.

I had something similar that searched for one key phrase and returned a row, but i need it to search for any string from an entire row of strings.

```
Sub STBP()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim desWS As Worksheet, srcWS As Worksheet, wkbSource As Workbook, response As String, LastRow As Long
    Set desWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales to be Processed")
    response = InputBox("Please enter the search string.")
    If response = "" Then Exit Sub
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\marc.delaney\Documents\TestSave\" 'change folder path to suit your needs
    ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
        With wkbSource
            LastRow = desWS.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set srcWS = .Sheets("Sales To Be Processed")
            srcWS.Unprotect Password:="cgeod18"
            With srcWS.Cells(7, 2).CurrentRegion
                .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="=*" & response & "*"
                desWS.Range("A" & LastRow + 1) = wkbSource.Name
                srcWS.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Copy desWS.Cells(desWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End With
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Columns.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the code you have tried in your question and explain the specific problems you are having with it.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Search+all+files+in+folder+excel+vba)?

Comment: @braX Thanks for your fast response. Let me find it out, its been a while :)

Comment: No, its only search for one word string, i need it to search about 30 exact strings, that ive put in a column, so maybe if it had a select strings messagebox or something that might work.

Comment: if its possible to have one macro to do that and then one to search for strings that start with a specific string, so like a partial match, thatd be great

Comment: @MarcosisKnows yes, you're right, there was nothing exactly answering you question. But if you break your question into parts and search - that would be quite easy. Give me some time to post an answer.

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak I didnt mean to come across as harsh its just the fact, that when youre a beginner at vba, making changes or piecing together different parts of code, is very difficult. I am learning, but im not quite there yet.

Comment: @braX Im not going to lie, i have no idea how to change this to suit my needs.
I have around 50-60 item codes, so turning them into arrays in that code would take alot of time and id like to future proof this, so that i can use it elsewhere if needed.
Also the fact that mine are password protected and that i need to copy and paste the rows to a master sheet, i dont think that post covers any of what im after.
Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've wrote in comment, you could have broken you task into a number of smaller and search by parts.

Here is an example of spoken above - your question step by step:
1. Take a folder with files;
2. Open each workbook one by one;
3. Look at each worksheet in opened workbook ([link that cover previous tasks (2d post)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel%20vba%20loop%20through%20sheets%20in%20a%20workbook));
4. Look through a specific range on each sheet of that workbook;
5. Copy a row if search match.

Here is my answer. I've tried to explain each step in comments, but in case something remains unclear - ask in comment.
Some notes before the code (all have comments within the code):
- there may be a problem with new sheets' in master workbook names
- you have do decide whether you want to use one target sheet per one source worksheet or per one source workbook

The code (may look too long and complicated, but that's mostly due to comments):

```
Sub STBP()
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim BrowseFolder As String

Dim checkRange As Range, r As Range ' check range and a variable for loop through it

Dim masterBook As Workbook  ' a master workbook
Dim sourceBook As Workbook  ' a source workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet        ' variable to loop through sheets
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet    ' sheet to copy found data to

Dim searchPattern As String    ' a string for search

' get the stockcode and check that it is entered
searchPattern = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Please enter the search string.", Title:="Enter the stockcode", Type:=2)
If searchPattern = "" Then Exit Sub

' refactor search pattern
searchPattern = "*" & searchPattern & "*"


' if the code is entered - start using memory for needed stuff
Set masterBook = ThisWorkbook
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' get the folder with File Dialog - don't need to hard code that
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the folder with source files"
        If Not .Show = 0 Then
            BrowseFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

' switch off screen blinking
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(BrowseFolder)

' loop through each file in folder
For Each FileItem In oFolder.Files
    ' if this is an excel file
    If FileItem.Name Like "*.xls*" Then
        ' open it for processing
        Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(BrowseFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name)

        ' loop through each sheet
        For Each sht In sourceBook.Sheets
            ' unprotect sheet and set a search range (column "F")
            With sht
                .Unprotect Password:="cgeod18"
                Set checkRange = Range(.Cells(1, 6), .Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp))
            End With

            ' loop through each cell in column "F"
            For Each r In checkRange
                ' check whether cell value contains the pattern
                If r.Text Like searchPattern Then
                    ' create new sheet in master workbook if there is a match
                    ' and a new target sheet for this workbook is not created yet
                    If targetSheet Is Nothing Then
                        Set targetSheet = masterBook.Sheets.Add(after:=masterBook.Sheets(masterBook.Sheets.Count))
                        ' rename target sheet to "Workbook_name-Sheet_name" to avoid same sheets naming
                        targetSheet.Name = FileItem.Name & "-" & sht.Name
                    End If

                    ' copy data
                    ' check whether first row has data
                    If targetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 And targetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Value = "" Then
                        r.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(1, 1)
                    Else
                        r.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=targetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            ' protect the sheet back
            sht.Protect Password:="cgeod18"

            ' use one target sheet per one source sheet
            ' uncomment next line if this is what you need and remove same line below
            'Set targetSheet = Nothing
        Next
        ' close the source workbook
        sourceBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If

    ' use one target sheet per one source workbook
    ' remove this line if you'd like to use one target sheet per one source sheet
    Set targetSheet = Nothing
Next

' set screen updating to normal state
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: beautiful. Ill check it out, get my head around it. Figure out exactly whats going on, via your awesome notes and ill confirm once tested :)

Comment: Hey,
Just wanted to check i have a list of about 30 stock codes. Do i have to enter each one seperately and do 30 different searches or can i put all of them in one search?

Comment: @MarcosisKnows At this time you can do it one by one, not all together.